# Twig code indentions in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, twig

The Twig plugin for Netbeans (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37069/php-twig) has some twig colouring functionality but it doesn't have any indentions. When I, for example, write some HTML code mixed with Twig code and then Right Click -> Format, the HTML code gets all the indentions etc. but the Twig code stays in the exact same place no matter how dirty it looks.

Any solutions for this? Couldn't find anything useful in Google.

Comment: you find soltion for that?

Answer (score 1):

It could be solved in [netbeans 8.0 RC](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/).

Try it and tell us!

Comment: but it is really better with the version 8.0 RC